# Loop through a javascript table and list elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to loop through a javascript table, I want to list the elements between two user chosen ones.

This is what the table looks like, for example, if the user chose Id 2 and 5, the loop should list lines 3 and 4. I tried with the For loop but with no results.

```
var station = [
  [0, 'JAMAA EL FNA', 'L1'],
  [1, 'KOUTOUBIA', 'L1'],
  [2, 'HOTEL DE VILLE', 'L1'],
  [3, 'R.P BERDII', 'L1'],
  [4, 'GRAND POSTE', 'L1'],
  [5, 'CAREE EDEN', 'L1'],
  [6, 'PL ABDELMOUMEN', 'L1'],
  [7, 'PLACE D ARMES', 'L1'],
  [8, 'FST', 'L1'],
  [9, 'SEMIRAMIS', 'L1'],
  [10, 'DR KUDIA', 'L1'],
  [11, 'MCDO', 'L1'],
  [12, 'CAFE AMINE', 'L1'],
  [13, 'FAC SEMLALIA', 'L1'],
  [14, 'ROUIDATE', 'L1'],
  [15, 'CLUB MINISTRE JUSTICE', 'L1'],
  [16, 'BEN TBIB', 'L1'],
  [17, 'ASWAK SALAM', 'L1'],
  [18, 'BAB DOUKALA', 'L1'],
  [19, 'JAMAA EL FNA', 'L2'],
  [20, 'KOUTOUBIA', 'L2']
];
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a javascript table.  What you have is a two dimensional array.

Comment: Please post the code you have. Then we can explain and correct your mistake. There are not many ways to iterate over an array. Presumably you got the comparison wrong (or have no comparison at all). Also explain exactly what you want to do (e.g. just log the data, update some DOM element, get a new array with only the "selected" items). Depending on this, other solutions may be more appropriate.

Comment: Since it is ordered, it sounds like OP wants to just filter the list based on the ID range given, A<X<B where A is min of 2 values, B is Max of 2 values.  `var result = station.filter( i => x[0] > A && x[0] < B);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select items by [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them:

```
let items = station.filter(curr => curr[0] > startNum && curr[0] < endNum)
```

```js
var station = [
  [0, 'JAMAA EL FNA', 'L1'],
  [1, 'KOUTOUBIA', 'L1'],
  [2, 'HOTEL DE VILLE', 'L1'],
  [3, 'R.P BERDII', 'L1'],
  [4, 'GRAND POSTE', 'L1'],
  [5, 'CAREE EDEN', 'L1'],
  [6, 'PL ABDELMOUMEN', 'L1'],
  [7, 'PLACE D ARMES', 'L1'],
  [8, 'FST', 'L1'],
  [9, 'SEMIRAMIS', 'L1'],
  [10, 'DR KUDIA', 'L1'],
  [11, 'MCDO', 'L1'],
  [12, 'CAFE AMINE', 'L1'],
  [13, 'FAC SEMLALIA', 'L1'],
  [14, 'ROUIDATE', 'L1'],
  [15, 'CLUB MINISTRE JUSTICE', 'L1'],
  [16, 'BEN TBIB', 'L1'],
  [17, 'ASWAK SALAM', 'L1'],
  [18, 'BAB DOUKALA', 'L1'],
  [19, 'JAMAA EL FNA', 'L2'],
  [20, 'KOUTOUBIA', 'L2']
];

const start = document.getElementById('start')
const end = document.getElementById('end')
const results = document.getElementById('results')

function changed() {
  let startNum = parseInt(start.value || -1)
  let endNum = parseInt(end.value || station.length + 1)
  let items = station.filter(curr => curr[0] > startNum && curr[0] < endNum)
  results.innerHTML = items.map(item => `<tr><td>${item[0]}</td><td>${item[1]}</td><td>${item[2]}</td></tr>`).join('')
}

changed()
start.addEventListener('input', changed)
end.addEventListener('input', changed)
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
Start: <input id="start" type="number"> End: <input id="end" type="number">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to filter you set, *stations*

```
var min = 2;
var max = 5;
var result = stations.filter( i => i[0] > min && i[0] < max);
```

This would return *result* which would contain the 2 rows where first column is 3 and 4.